# Jquery mobile forms and validation using Sqllite

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery mobile and I wish to create a form which has Username and password in first HTML file and I need to store these datas in sqlite and retrieve an compare datas and if I enter the different login details ie..(Username and password) it should prompt an error message.

After completing the login I have to register the details and after the registration is completed,its gets stored in sqlite database and if we want to edit these details the edited details gets stored again in the database.

May I know the concept,methods and the reference so it will be helpful for me

Comment: Please do comment if this is not clear and I will happy to explain these in detail

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication